# Python: Interpolate data to specific x values

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, interpolation

I have a problem, that should be typical in science but I couldn't find a solution yet.

I have a data set in a cvs file, e.g.:
[image]

What I need is to bring the data in this format, so I can directly compare them with other data, because they have the same x values:
[image]

The y values should be a linear interpolation from the original data.
I'm complete open to any python package (numpy, pandas, scipy,...).

I have a solution in excel but I want to automate that step, as I collect all the data in python.

Thank you in advance

Olli

Comment: Please [edit] to include your sample input and output data in the text of your question, not as a picture or link, to make a [mcve]

Answer (score 3):

Numpy has a nice way of doing it:

```
import numpy as np

x = [0, 0.53, 0.84, 1.25, 1.55]
y = [0.523, 0.723, 0.965, 1.251, 1.458]

new_x = [0, 0.5, 1.0, 1.5]
new_y = np.interp(new_x, x, y)

new_y
```

Comment: I would just like to add you'll probably end up generating `new_x` with `np.linspace`. Here it'd be `np.linspace(0, 1.5, 4)`.